# dwij laraadmin - multiple role based login

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, laravel, laraadmin

hi iam using [these admin package](https://laraadmin.com/docs/1.0). this package provide CRUD opertion and roles and logins,now i want to customize the login controller. i search in all folers,there is no login controller. can anyone find out to customize login controller in these package.

this is version iam using

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "dwij/laraadmin": "1.0.40"
    }
```

in my folder structure there is no controller
[image]

Answer (score 1):

in the [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController](https://github.com/dwijitsolutions/laraadmin/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php#L8) you should see:

```
...
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    ...
```

the [`login(Request $request`)](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.html#method_login) method that handle the authentication is included in `AuthenticatesUsers` so if you want to use your own method just define a new login() method in the LoginController like this:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    ...

    public function login(Request $request) {
        //your logic
    }

    ...
```

Comment: thanks man.so, i can write my own controller right?

Comment: here, i need to verfiy the user and set token in session  cookies, and also save roles in application storage

Comment: the controller should be : App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController, just create a login function and you can customize the login logic there. you can see the original login login in (Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers)[https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L31) Orif you are using Laravel 5.0 you can find it here (Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers)[https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php#L71)

Comment: i attached screen shot of my folder structure.

my authController are using these 


```namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Role;
use Validator;
use Eloquent;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

Comment: yes you're using Laravel 5, so inside the AuthController you can overwrite the login method by defining `postLogin()`, the base of this method is defined in [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php#L71)

Comment: hi Hichem, iused that postLogin() into AuthController,but its wont working

Comment: please can i see the routes/web.php of yours ?